# how to define a linear function WX+b in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am practicing pytorch. I want to define a linear function Y=WX+B for inputs shape as (3,32,32) and output, the same shape i.e. (3, 32, 32). I defined m network as:

```
class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()

        # defining the parameters 'w' and 'b'
        w =  torch.empty((batch_size, 3, 32, 32 ), requires_grad = True)
        b = torch.empty((1, 3, 32, 32 ), requires_grad = True)

   def forward(x):
       y_pred = w * x + b

       return y_pred
```

Am I doing it right? Because I am getting error for it. Here is the error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2d4af008a939> in <module>
     40     image= torch.rand((8, 3, 32, 32 ))
     41     model= Denoiser_AutoEncoder()
---> 42     print(model(image))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _forward_unimplemented(self, *input)
    199         registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.
    200     """
--> 201     raise NotImplementedError
    202 
    203 

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: Your class is defined as Linear, but the error message shows you're instantiating a different class Denoiser_AutoEncoder?

Comment: I corrected the spelling mistake and changed Denoser_autoencoder to Linear, but get same error. I also tried torch.randn instead of torch.empty but got same error. Am I defining my network correct? Do I need to flatten my data first or this way should be fine?

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please consider upvoting. Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for starters, PyTorch has a Linear layer which is documented here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html
You can use it by instantiating in your **init**:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)
    
def forward(self, x):
    y_pred = self.linear(x)
    return y_pred
```

I believe the error you're seeing is because you're not instantiating a PyTorch layer anywhere but your Linear class inherits from nn.Module, so it's looking for PyTorch layers when you call forward() on it. Note that you can create a network without using the existing Linear() layer from PyTorch, in which case you just remove the nn.Module from your class.

The second thing is that as you suspect, you'd want to Flatten your data on input (or more typically use a CNN on images). Flatten is documented here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html#flatten.